# Why does unserialize in PHP keep returning false?

Tags: php, serialization

I've just written the easiest script in the world, but still I can't get it to work, and it's mighty strange.

I want to use jQuery to catch some input field values and serialize them with jQuery's `serialize()`. I then send the serialized string to the server to unserialize it. Here's the output I get from the serializing in jQuery, this is what I send to the server.

```
field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3
```

And here's the function,

```
public function unserialize_input()
{
    $str = $this->input->post("user_values");
    $unserialized = unserialize($str);
    var_dump($unserialized);
}
```

As I said, if I go "echo $str;" I get "field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3", so the string should be unserializable. However, I always get the same error message and the `var_dump($unserialized);` always returns bool(false).

Here's the error message I get from [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter), the framework I'm using for PHP.

```
Severity: Notice
Message: unserialize() [<ahref='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 0 of 41 bytes

bool(false)
```

I'm using [MAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) and run this locally at the moment. I read something about `magic_quotes_gpc` being OFF could cause this locally, but it's enabled. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You're using the wrong PHP function. You should use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) instead.

```
 parse_str($str, $unserialized);
```

Answer (score 4):

PHP's [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) destruct and construct PHP objects/arrays/values.

jQuery [serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) serializes a form into a POST string which can be very handy to do Ajax calls on. A post string is not a valid serialized string in PHP and cannot be reconstructed to a PHP mixed value and thus it returns false.

Comment: Ok, so that's the reason. Thank you. Do you have any suggestion on how I can handle the data in the PHP script? As you said, it's really handy to send the input values as a serialized string in jQuery with the ajax call. But is there anyway I can convert the serialized string back into a php array or some other data type that php can handle easily, for example to insert the data into a database.

Comment: if you've sent the data with ajax, it will be in $_GET or $_POST, depending on the method you used for ajax

Comment: Or to stay in the technology stack that you chose you could do the ajax call with $.post with jQuery and send the data as JSON. CodeIgniter can can reconstruct JSON to a php object/array/value checkout the json helper: http://blog.jdbartlett.com/2007/09/codeigniter-servicesjson.html. You can think of JSON as a universal format for serialze() and unserialize in a way.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a bit vague because I don't know jQuery overly well, but could it be that jQuery serialize's strings even slightly different from PHP? If so, then that would cause the error message that you see.

Comment: That might be true, but still, the string looks fine I think

"field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3" even if I generate it with PHP or jQuery it looks ok, shouldn't it be unserializable? Or am I getting this wrong?